# LinktoPrevious not working in powershell for section break

Tags: powershell, ms-word

i am trying to put different header and footer dynamically on each page by dividing into sections
 and making linktoprevios false but it gives this error message

**Property 'LinkToPrevious' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
 At D:\work\scripts_done\abcd\config.ps1:19 char:36
+             $Doc.LastSection.HeadersFooters. <<<< LinkToPrevious = $false;
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (LinkToPrevious:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound**

Whats wrong in this ...... my documents takes only 26 line in a page i m trying to inserting header footer on each page

```
$target_dir="D:\ABCD"
$dir="$target_dir"
$val=ls $dir
$filename="D:\ABCD\er.txt"
$filedata = (get-content $filename)
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application;
$Word.Visible = $true;
$Doc = $Word.Documents.Add();
$selection.Font.Name="Courier New"  
$selection.Font.Size=11
$selection.Font.Spacing=0.5
$selection=$word.Selection
$count=0
foreach ( $line in $filedata ){
        if ( $count -eq 26 ){
            $Doc.LastSection.HeadersFooters.Header.Add("abcd $count");
            $Doc.AddSection();
            $Doc.LastSection.HeadersFooters.LinkToPrevious = $false;
            $count=0;
        }
        $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAICR the LinkToPrevious is not for the section, but for the individual headers/footers. But the HeadersFooters collection is an oddity anyway. I'm thinking in VBA here, not PowerShell, but I'm not sure even your line

```
$Doc.LastSection.HeadersFooters.Header.Add("abcd $count");
```

will work. Assuming $Doc.LastSection gives you a Word Section object, I think you need something more like the following, suitably adjusted for PowerShell

```
$Doc.LastSection.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "abcd $count"
$Doc.AddSection()
$Doc.LastSection.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = $false;
```

Comment: it gives this error

Unexpected token 'wdHeaderFooterPrimary' in expression or statement.

Comment: Then try the constant equivalent:
$Doc.LastSection.Headers(1).Range.Text = "abcd $count"

and so on...

Comment: do you have something to read on power and word doc which can help me in this case as i am new to this and searched alot but didn't find anything good........i have seen some code versions related to this in vba or c# 
http://www.syncfusion.com/support/kb/291/Is%20it%20possible%20to%20create%20different%20Header%20and%20footer%20in%20a%20word%20document

 but need in powershell

Comment: Not really - I always start the VBA Editor and look at View->Object Broswer for object model info, try entering some code in VBA where I  get some "code completion" help, or try recording some vba and look at the output of the recorder. Translating the VBA code into the required programming language is usually a mechanical process but you have to know (or learn) the rules for your target language - if, for example, it doesn't know about the enumerations/constant names defined in the relevant Object Model, then you have to look them up.